# Different execution and input character set in C

Tags: c, gcc

I am trying to understand the C standard. In particular this part from C99:

> § 5.1.1.2 1.5 Each source character set member and escape sequence in character constants and string literals is converted to the corresponding memeber of the execution character set; if there is no corresponding member, it is converted to and implementation-defined member other than the null (wide) character.

I made this example code,

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    printf("Ø");
}
```

and when I try to compile this with GCC with `-std=C99 -fexec-charset=ASCII`, I get the error

```
foo.c:5:9: error: converting to execution character set: Invalid or incomplete multibyte or wide character
  printf("Ø");
         ^
```

Shouldn't the 'Ø' just be converted to an implementation-defined ASCII charcter and compile according to the quote above?

Comment: But is it in "source character set"? I think it is not. Try "-fwide-exec-charset". Also "-finput-charset" is setting the character set of the source file itself.

Answer (score 0):

I have a header file with Unicode characters worked fine in Visual Studio 2015, but won't compile in GCC with this error, I tried to use Notepad++ to open it, click the Encoding menu, and converted it into UTF-8, which seems to work for my GCC compilation.[image: using Notepad++ to chanage encoding]